# In IE7 navigation didn't show properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

```
**HTML**
<ul class="navlist">
    <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="agenda.html">Agenda</a></li>
    <li><a href="speaker.html">Speakers</a></li>
</ul>

**CSS**
.navlist {  
    margin :0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navlist li a {   
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:18px;
    color:white;
    background:#63B3E4;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    border-right:1px solid white;
}

.navlist li a:hover {
color:#63B3E4;
background:white;}

.navlist li {
    float: left;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c9g969sk/)
In IE7 navigation didn't show properly. Padding not properly taken in IE7. How to fix this issue. Issue is only internet explorer 7.

Comment: It is looking good only in IE7. Any screenshot??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't IE here, so it's just a tip:

```
.navlist li a {display: block}
```